# how to force a locale to widget

Tags: android

I am working on an android app, so far I have added setting for changing the locale, so that a user can have the locale in the app different than that one on the device, now all activities are working well but the widget still uses device's locale not that one set to the app.

Is  there a way to force the widget to use other locale than that set on the device like activities?

thanks

Answer (score -1):

I put the languages in a spinner. I save the chosen locale in preferences (prefs) and use it in the onConfigurationChanged method where I change the locale. I presume you do the same or similar.
The trick is that in the OnItemSelected method of the Spinner I also call OnConfigurationChanged, set the text from resources and invalidate all affected widgets. Voilá! All the text is shown in the selected language.

```
spLanguages.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
    prefs.saveInt("language", spLanguages.getSelectedItemPosition());
    lan = spLanguages.getSelectedItemPosition();
    onConfigurationChanged(new Configuration());
    btnStart.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.main_start));
    btnStart.invalidate();
}
@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {}
});
```

Comment: this has nothing to do with the widget, @mmohab already knows how to do it in an activity. In theory the widget can read sharedpreferences onUpdate, but onUpdate doesn't always run